# Searching multiple strings

Tags: string, perl, search, replace

How can i search from set of strings

i would like a perl script to search for either `"aaa", "bbb", "ccc", "ddd"`

Searching from txt file

Example 1

```
some random text
blah
blah 
blah
//Car/trunk/sandbox/users/Tom/xyz/bbb/toyota
```

Desired Output:

```
//Car/trunk/sandbox/users/Tom/xyz/...
```

Example 2

```
some random text
blah
blah 
blah
//Car/trunk/sandbox/users/Alex/abc/defg/ddd/honda/accord
```

Desired Output:

```
//Car/trunk/sandbox/users/Alex/abc/defg/...
```

Basically searching from the given set of strings from `"aaa", "bbb", "ccc", "ddd"` it finds `"bbb"` in example 1 and takes everything before and adds back slash with `"..."`

Please note that it is reading from one text file, example 1 is a example of text file and same goes for example 2.

So far this is what i have.

```
my $infile = 'new5.txt';
    my @strings  = qw/aaa bbb ccc ddd/;
    local @ARGV = ($infile);
    while( <> ){

        print;
    }
```

Comment: Does the string you are matching have to be inside slashes, e.g. `../aaa/..` should match but not `../aaardvark/..`?

Comment: Perl's got great documentation.  Start here: http://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html

Comment: has to be inside slashes ../aaa/.., sorry forgot to mention that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The code you have so far is what I would call a hackish way to cat a file.
First of all, we will get the obligatory pragmas out of the way:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use autodie;
```

The last one makes sure the script dies if a file was not found or could not be opened.
You initialized $infile and @strings correctly, good.

The proper or more accepted way to open and loop over the contents of a file is this:

```
open(my $FILE, "<", $infile);
while(my $line = <$FILE>) {
   chomp $line;
   ...
}
close($FILE);
```

Within this loop you want to try to match each element of the `@strings` array. That can be accomplished by looping over each element in the array:

```
foreach my $elem (@strings) {
    ...
}
```

In this loop you want to do the match. If it does, print out what you need (and go the next line in the file). Look up the `perlre` man page to see what the stuff after `=~` is doing:

```
if ($line =~ m#/$elem/#) {
    print SOMETHING;
    next;
}
```

What would that SOMETHING be? According to the `perlvar` man page, `$`` (among other mnemonics) is the variable that contains the string before the matched string:

```
print $`."/...\n";
```

Put it all together and you have your script.